# Custom annotation for userlocation pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Can seems to change the users location annotation image.
Maybe someone could see where i am mistaken if...

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
        MKAnnotationView *annoationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
        [annoationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"melocation"] ];
        return annoationView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the annotation for the first time when it can't be dequeued:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        static NSString* const kAnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
        MKAnnotationView *annoationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kAnnotationIdentifier];
        if (!annoationView) {
            annoationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:kAnnotationIdentifier];
        }
        [annoationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"melocation"] ];
        return annoationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```